# Remove "www" from domain with Apache2 for HTTPS?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, redirect

Just installed a new fresh 12.04 ubuntu server.

Always used the boilerplate redirection to remove www but it looked like it did not support https so I started looking around. Tried everything I found & somehow http "www" removal works well but https won't redirect.

Here is what I use (in a bp_rewrite.conf file in /etc/apache2/conf.d) :

```
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
  RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: What do you mean "https won't redirect"? The webserver doesn't send a redirect, or some other error??

Comment: It will stay lazily on the `https://www.website.com` while if I enter `http://www.website.com` I correctly get redirected to `http://website.com`

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the rule, so it must not be running the rule at all for https. How do you have your https site configured? Is this rule in the global configuration and the https site a virtual host?

Comment: Yep global rule in conf.d & virtual host. Should I put the rule in the virtual host?

Comment: Do you have any similar rules (or rules with the [L] flag, like the one you posted) in your Virtual Host or `.htaccess` file? The virtual host by default will inherit this rule, but will run inherited rules *after* any virtual host or `.htaccess` rewrite rules; though this could also be turned off (by a `RewriteOptions` directive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code looks slightly overly complicated, but very close to what I use:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s%{HTTP_HOST} ^(on(s)|offs).+\.(.+\..+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%2://%3$1 [R=301]
```

Note: This simply rips anything off the front of the domain name's last two parts. So your user could enter `what.the.example.com` and it would reduce it to `example.com`. If your domain name is `example.co.uk` or something with three parts the end of the first line would have to be modified to fit.

Comment: This does not work for one use case though:  if I enter [https://www.dom.com](http://example.com)(https://www.dom.com), it again returns [https://www.dom.com](http://example.com)(https://www.dom.com).   For http: it removes the www and rewrites to https though.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the `RewriteRule` to trigger, both `RewriteCond` directives has to be true.

How about this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Now, if just one of the conditions remain true (as for `https://www.example.com/`, where only the first condition is true), the `RewriteRule` is applied

Comment: Now this would turn https on anytime it's not on already... Still not what he's asking for.